# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |a|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, analysis

I know this is a basic question, but I could not find a question on the site about exactly this question, even by using https://approach0.xyz/search/ Maybe I searched wrongly ?

> Show that
> $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a 
> \;\implies\; 
> \lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |a|$.

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Show that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a 
\;\implies\; 
\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |a|
$$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$ means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$ there is $|x_n - a| < \epsilon$

Using the triangle inequality:
$$
\epsilon > |x_n - a| \geq \bigl| |x_n| - |a| \bigr| 
$$

But $\epsilon > \bigl| |x_n| - |a| \bigr|$ is the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |a|$

This completes the proof.

---

Note that the reverse claim
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a 
\;\Longleftarrow\; 
\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |a|
$$

does not hold in general. For example if $x_n = (-1)^n$ then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = 1$$ but
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \neq 1$$

The exception being for $a = 0$, because in this case
\begin{align}
\bigl| |x_n| - 0 \bigr| < \epsilon 
\; &\Longleftrightarrow \; 
|x_n - 0| < \epsilon \\[4pt]
\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n| = |0| 
\; &\Longleftrightarrow \; 
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n  = 0 
\end{align}

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact way to do it, with the reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for your quick reply. Feel free to post your comment as answer if you want, so I can accept it. I'm honestly surprised  I did not find this question on the site, but again maybe I used the wrong search terms

Comment: Your algebra is fine but I would very much recommend you pay more attention to writing up your proof and making sure that the logic is clear.  For example, the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_n|=|a|$ is not "$\epsilon>||x_n|-|a||$", it is "for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists (etc etc)".

Comment: An alternative approach would be to split into two cases: $a\geq 0$ and $a<0.$

Comment: Notation: use `|x|` for absolute value $|x|$, as `\mid` has built in horizontal whitespace for building sets: $\{x \in A \mid x \notin B\}$

Comment: @SammyBlack The recommended way to typeset absolute values is `\lvert x \rvert`.  For example, `|\sin x|` results in the incorrect spacing $|\sin x|$, whereas `\lvert \sin x \rvert` gives the correct spacing $\lvert \sin x \rvert$.

Comment: Moreover, since the absolute value is a continuous function the result follows directly.

Comment: @L.F. You're right, of course. I was suggesting just the bar, as it looks a lot better than `\mid` (which formats with `\mathrel` class I believe) without needing separate symbols with `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` classes. For the OP, some of this is explained briefly [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38984/3905).

Comment: Well done for searching! When I look for "limit of absolute value", I find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/799115/473276) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463375/473276), which are fairly similar. Much discussion here is under "continuity of the absolute value/modulus function", eg [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/660138/473276), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4550611/473276) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2261498/473276) (although the last one is more topological). It's even a special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8066/473276).